# Where and how to replace the server code of the ProFTPD project?

Tags: c

I am working on a research project which I have to support soon. It consists in modifying the code of the ProFTPD project at the address https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd using a C implementation of the Quic protocol https://github.com/private-octopus/picoquic from Google.

**My objectid aims to change the TCP transport protocol used by proftpd by the transport protocol**

I modified this code the following code https://github.com/private-octopus/picoquic/blob/master/sample/sample_server.c to have a Quic server,I named my function **init_quic();**

I then went to the proftpd code, more precisely in the file https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/blob/master/src/inet.c, I noticed that it is a socket which is used
**fd = socket (addr_family, SOCK_STREAM, tcp_proto);**

and in the file https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/blob/master/src/main.c at line 2499 its **init_inet()** launch;

Suppose my function is called init_quic (); how to implement in this code proftpd so that the started server is a Quic based server?